# Looping through paragraphs (skipping the first three) throws an overflow error

Tags: vba, ms-word

Basically, I have some MS Word documents that are structed the same way:

The first three paragraphs are the title and two blank ones.

Then, each paragraph is composed by three parts, each one separated by a tab: character name  timecode  dialogue

The character names can't have spaces in the middle whatsoever (John Doe should be JohnDoe)

I cooked up this little subroutine:

```
Sub RemoveSpacesFromCharacterNames()

' Counter variable to track the paragraph number
Dim paragraphCounter As Integer

' Loop through each paragraph in the document
For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

' Increment the counter variable
paragraphCounter = paragraphCounter + 1

' Check if the paragraph is the first three paragraphs
If paragraphCounter > 3 Then

' Check if the paragraph contains three parts separated by tabs
If Split(p.Range.Text, vbTab).Count = 3 Then
    Dim charName As String, timeCode As String, dialogue As String
    charName = Split(p.Range.Text, vbTab)(0)
    timeCode = Split(p.Range.Text, vbTab)(1)
    dialogue = Split(p.Range.Text, vbTab)(2)

    ' Remove any spaces from the character name
    charName = Replace(charName, " ", "")

    ' Reconstruct the paragraph with the updated character name
    p.Range.Text = charName & vbTab & timeCode & vbTab & dialogue
End If
End If
Next p
End Sub
```

However it just crashes MS Word, saying that line 9 (paragraphCounter = paragraphCounter + 1) overflows and it gets stuck on "charName = Replace(charName, " ", "")"

It's weird because the test document only has 5 paragraphs (3 + 2)

What can possibly be causing the infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `Split` function yields an array with a base index of 0, so it doesn't possess a `.Count` property. In this case, you should use
  `Ubound`.
- Modifying by `p.Range.Text` for the entire paragraph can disrupt the `For Each` iterator, as it replaces the paragraph mark. This may lead to an infinite loop.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RemoveSpacesFromCharacterNames()
    ' Counter variable to track the paragraph number
    Dim paragraphCounter As Integer
    Dim subPara, p As Paragraph
    ' Loop through each paragraph in the document
    For paragraphCounter = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
        If paragraphCounter > 3 Then
            Set p = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(paragraphCounter)
            ' Check if the paragraph contains three parts separated by tabs
            subPara = Split(p.Range.Text, vbTab)
            If UBound(subPara) = 2 Then
                ' Remove any spaces from the character name
                subPara(0) = Replace(subPara(0), " ", "")
                ' Reconstruct the paragraph with the updated character name
                p.Range.Text = Join(subPara, vbTab)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

A code snippet that illustrates the challenges associated with updating paragraphs using a `For Each` loop. The output consists of the first paragraph (`ABC` is the 1st para.) `repeated five times` instead of including the content of the first five paragraphs.

```
Sub ForEachLoop()
    Dim sTxt As String, p As Paragraph, i As Integer
    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        i = i + 1
        sTxt = p.Range.Text
        Debug.Print sTxt 
        p.Range.Text = sTxt
        If i > 5 Then Exit For
    Next
End Sub
```

Output: The result of

```
ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC
```

Of course, updating paragraphs can be accomplished when using a `For Each` loop if preferred.

```
Sub ForEachLoop2()
    Dim sTxt As String, p As Paragraph, i As Integer
    Dim pRange As Range
    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        Set pRange = ActiveDocument.Range(p.Range.Start, p.Range.End - 1)
        i = i + 1
        sTxt = pRange.Text
        Debug.Print sTxt
        pRange.Text = sTxt
        If i > 5 Then Exit For
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Update:

> Question: The only caveat I found is that it clears all formatting and comments, but I don't think join and split can handle formatting, can they?

> Utilizing Word's built-in replace function to replace spaces will not impact the existing formatting and comments.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub RemoveSpacesFromCharacterNames()
    ' Counter variable to track the paragraph number
    Dim paragraphCounter As Integer
    Dim subPara, p As Paragraph, iStart As Long
    ' Loop through each paragraph in the document
    For paragraphCounter = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
        If paragraphCounter > 3 Then
            Set p = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(paragraphCounter)
            ' Check if the paragraph contains three parts separated by tabs
            subPara = Split(p.Range.Text, vbTab)
            If UBound(subPara) = 2 Then
                iStart = p.Range.Start
                With ActiveDocument.Range(iStart, iStart + Len(subPara(0))).Find
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                    .Text = " "
                    .Replacement.Text = ""
                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindStop
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! And I thought it would be simpler!
The only caveat I found is that it clears all formatting and comments, but I don't think join and split can handle formatting, can they?

Comment: They can't. All roads lead to Rome. I have updated the code.